# "Diablo-esque" game that runs on linux (preferably free)

Tags: software-recommendation, games

Is there any game with similar gameplay to Diablo II/III that is playable on linux? My preliminary google search yielded no results and on steam I didnt find any game similar to diablo.. I thought i found one (strife) but it turned out to be a moba that had a diablo like intro...

Comment: Note that this question doesn't meet [the requirements](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/15641/513090) for the `software-recommendation` tag.  Most of the questions intended for that tag really should be on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ anyway.

Comment: [Diablo](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=73). Most isometric Blizzard games are, reportedly, [well supported by Wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?bIsQueue=false&bIsRejected=false&sClass=vendor&iId=26&sAction=view&sTitle=View+Developer) and can thus run under Linux.

Comment: Looking at some of the recs given in the answers, I agree with @NH. - this could do with some more description of what "Diablo-esque" means, in the question body. Path of Exile? Yep, definitely. Pillars of Eternity? Ehhh, kinda, maybe. Wesnoth? great game, but no.

Comment: @papajo would I be correct in guessing that action-oriented (or realtime) gameplay is important? I can think of several non-realtime games that are pretty similar to Diablo on most *other* things that I'd consider core features, but I'm also assuming that you want action-oriented rather than turn-based game.

Comment: Not free, but I found [Victor Vran](http://store.steampowered.com/app/345180/Victor_Vran_ARPG/) to be quite nice. Visually it's similar to Diablo 3, but gameplay-wise it's much better.

Comment: @NH. Somebody else edited that tag to my post.

Comment: @TobiaTesan There is a huge difference 1) well supported doesnt mean without caveats at all 2) it is written with DX11 in mind which wine doesnt support so the graphics will take a hit when running under DX9 mode 3) I am not interested in paying money for the 3 licenses in order to play a game that my main machine wont run with the same graphical fidelity and the same redundancy as it should.

Comment: @Ethan Kaminski your assumptions are correct.

Comment: this may suit more on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @papajo *Diablo* (not Diablo III or IV or...) was released in the DirectX 2.0 or 3.0 era, and "Silver" or "Gold" support usually means "runs better than in current Windows", probably you'll have issues with modem play or exotic stuff like that :) So I thought it was worth pointing out, but hey, I'm not on the Blizzard payroll ;)

Comment: Check out Titan Quest and the follower by the same team, Grim Dawn. Apparently they run well on Wine, and they're great games, especially Titan Quest which has a lot of character.

Comment: I've played [Neverwinter Nights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neverwinter_Nights) a very long time ago, it has a native Linux client and I remember it was a brilliant game. But I can't add this as an answer because I'm not sure where you can get the original game. I can only find what seems to be a "Diamond version" and I don't know if it works on Linux without wine (Though I've seen posts around the Internet saying it is possible but I cannot confirm).

Comment: @NH. I thought there was enough to add the tag. Diablo is (and has remained) a *very particular* type of game, both in how it looks, what you do and the story arcing within the game. It may not be easy to describe in other words but that does not mean it is unanswerable or that there are too many answers. People who have played the Diablo games (not a small number) have all the information they need to base a good recommendation upon. And please note that the post you're linking to isn't law here. There are higher-voted answers in that thread that don't go that far.

Comment: Back in the day there was a game called "S.C.O.U.R.G.E - Heroes of Lesser Renoun".  https://sourceforge.net/projects/scourge/  No idea if it's still going.

Comment: A software recommendation that yields 10 answers (most of them deleted, since they were nothing but links), tells that this was a poorly scoped SR.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think the closest games to Diablo are Torchlight 1 ([Humble Bundle Store](https://www.humblebundle.com/store/torchlight)) and its successor Torchlight 2 ([Humble Bundle Store](https://www.humblebundle.com/store/torchlight) or on [GoG](https://www.gog.com/game/torchlight_ii)). In fact, part of the developers of these games, were inside the Diablo development team.

Comment: That one looks good, have not played but only 2 seems to be on Linux?

Comment: I think it exists a linux port of the first one. I bought the game as a part of a humble bundle.

Comment: @S.Ith: I added links to Humble Bundle and GoG which sell Linux ports of one or both games.

Comment: @MarkKirby: Humble Bundle claims to carry a Linux port (see my edit to the answer). Could be a Wine bundle, though that means the developer/publisher feels confident enough in the stability of the Wine wrapper at least with the redistributed Wine version.

Comment: Torchlight 1 runs fine under Wine.

Comment: Good call. These are great games.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I have the humble bundle Linux version. It's a native game, but last time I checked it had some pretty daunting glitches such as the character's face not showing up. Part of the reason that version has never made it to Steam, I guess. On the upside though it has the ferret pet, which is an otherwise limited edition retail box exclusive thing.

Comment: Yup Torchlight 2 seems to be the most fitting candidate although I hoped for a free game to be honest :P Anyway lets not be greedy I already found a steamkey for a discount @ 7.9euros  :) Thanks for advice! ^^

Comment: Torchlight & Torchlight II is currently on sale, 75% off on GoG

Comment: @papajo: Steam keys resold at a "discount" are often bought with stolen credit card information to the detriment of the game publisher who has to deal with fraud charge-backs which end up *costing* them money. Especially small publishers and game development studios would prefer that you pirate their products instead of buying them via resold keys.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Meh Steam is the company that deals with the transactions and I dont pitty them at all that fatguy gaben and his friends have already made stacks of millions of USD even if they get 0 profit for now on his grandchildren will still be rich...  thats why he'll never bother with HL3.. As for the stolen CC again I dont care since they are insured and ppl  get their money back as for my case in particular they use to buy them on Sales or with promotions and sell them later on to guys like me at a lower price tag (lower than the current price without sales offers or promotions)

Comment: @papajo: I wasn't even talking about the credit card owners. I was talking about game development studios who are slapped with fees for the CC transaction reversal based on claims of fraud which makes them *lose money* on the sale. Yes, the fraud claim is held *against the developer*, not the CC thief or Steam. Some developers literally provide *legal* torrents for their games to discourage the use of resold keys to buy their games because of how much it hurts them.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I find this extremely hard to believe what fees? I worked in a retail shop and also had an ebay account refunding credit cards was always free of charge without any fees why should there be fees? fees for what? not being able to know if the guy who bought something from them is a thief? since when is a business owner required to be a detective? thats work for the police.. I think the best case scenario is that this story is some kind of an urban myth to encourage people buy from places with higher profit margins.

Comment: @papajo: Charge-back conditions and fees vary depending on what the seller and its payment provider negotiate which depends on the region, industry and power of the seller. See https://unknownworlds.com/blog/beware-shady-key-resellers-and-discount-steam-keys/ for a primary source for my earlier claim. *Money* quote: “This means we never received payment for the game. In fact, we were charged a fee by the card issuer for the charge-back. For these 1,341 keys, these fees totalled around $30,000.”

Comment: @DavidFoerster your source is a blog post.. and its ultimate bullshit. The card issuer  takes the loss not the client neither the seller. Also 23$ feels on a 25$ purchase is an other sign of them being full of BS... even if there would be a charge back fee involved it would rather be something like 1$ (like other paypal or bank fees for transferring money to accounts etc) not almost the 90% of the total price lol.  https://goo.gl/wa2u8k <- For more info read  this, yes, Quore is not necessarily more credible but the 1st post is the best tldr i could find and has credible references.

Answer (score 21):

If you have a system with enough muscle (mine is a Core2Quad 2.7 GHz, 4 GB RAM when I played the game regularly ), I've found that the *free*<sup>1</sup> game *[Path of Exile](https://www.pathofexile.com/game)* runs reasonably well (instructions are available for installing with [Wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=13810) or PlayOnLinux).

Compared to Diablo, it's like moving up from Tic-Tac-Toe to four-player Pente -- it's a MMO isometric, with seven character classes, ten acts, huge numbers of item drops, maps, and it's "live" -- that is, new material is still being added on a regular basis, as one might expect for an MMO.

---

<sup>1</sup> “free” as in “free beer”. It’s not open source software. The game development is (supposedly well) funded through purchasable player and weapon skins, a sales strategy dubbed “pay-to-shine”.

Comment: (Commenting with a level 90 SSF exile idling in the background.) Worth noting that *PoE* is, at the high end, **much** more difficult than *Diablo* or *Diablo II* (I could not tolerate *D3* long enough to try its high-level content). On a personal level, frustratingly so. I love the game, but the high-end stuff is just obnoxious. This character is my first, and almost-certainly last, to hit 90.

Comment: That might be because you played SSF...  Come join us in Harbinger Hardcore and play as a team, and you'll find yourself at 92 and not even realise what happened.

Comment: @AdamBarnes I certainly would notice, because I would have to coordinate and schedule my mindless monster killing around other people, utterly ruining the fun of the game for me. I am SSF solely because *I do not want to have to spend time interacting with random other people while playing*. (And hardcore is just so many kinds of not my cup of tea; even the “mere” 10% penalty loss on softcore death had me ready to break something while trying to get from 89 to 90.)

Comment: @KRyan The game is not balanced for solo self-found. You'll never find all the items you need alone in reasonable time, the basic idea of that game is that you should trade for them. High-level play goes a lot smoother if you trade, at least occasionally.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I am aware. I consider that a failure in the game’s design, and frankly, a dereliction of duty on the part of GGG to rely on trading to fix the problems with their balance and drop systems.

Comment: @KRyan They are not compatible goals. GGG explicitly wants trading and player interaction, and balancing for ssf would break that. I hate their trade system too, but if they wanted a D3-like self-find only balanced system, they would probably have done it.

Comment: @KRyan and that is why I play D3 over PoE, the minute I knew that I had to deal with other people in order to succeed, I quit the game.

Answer (score 12):

Just to help you find stuff yourself, I'd categorise Diablo as an *isometric action RPG*.

There are probably a few options here but in the non-free camp:

- [Freeablo](https://freeablo.org/) is an engine reimplementation of Diablo 1
- Wine can be used to play the Windows clients. For example, [Diablo 3 does work quite well](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=29952) (with caveats).
- [Victor Vran](http://store.steampowered.com/app/345180/Victor_Vran_ARPG/) is very similar in gameplay and tone to Diablo. Again, non-free. (I honestly hadn't seen the comment on the head post! Thought this independently when I saw the recommendation for Torchlight)

Answer (score 8):

[FLARE](http://flarerpg.org/) is pretty much word-for-word what you asked for: Diablo-like, runs on Linux, free. It's been a few versions since I played it, so I don't know how much depth there is to it nowadays, but it was good for a couple of hours' hacking and slashing even back when I first discovered it.

It may be worth noting that FLARE is both an engine (the name stands for **F**ree/**L**ibre **A**ction **R**oleplaying **E**ngine) and the included game built on it; it seems like maybe the preferred capitalisation for the *game* is [Flare](https://github.com/clintbellanger/flare-game)?

Comment: Plus it's available via the repositories: `sudo apt install flare`

Answer (score 3):

Some (arguably most) of the [Soldak Entertainment](http://www.soldak.com/) games are similar to Diablo, such as [Din's Curse](http://store.steampowered.com/app/217290/Dins_Curse/) or [Zombasite](http://store.steampowered.com/app/408960/Zombasite/).

Both are isometric action RPGs where gameplay consists primarily of an isometric action-RPG dungeon crawl where you acquire random loot and build up your character. Soldak games do tend to add some additional quirks, though (such as procedurally generated quests).

I've gone with Steam links, due to personal preference. The games are also available from the developer's website directly.

Other games from the studio may also be worth looking into, such as [Drox Operative](http://store.steampowered.com/app/274480/Drox_Operative/) (a Soldak-style diablo-like "in space!", as it were).

Answer (score -1):

Tales of Maj'Eyal aka TOME.

https://te4.org/

free as in freedom. dungeon crawling roguelike.

Comment: Diablo is not rogue-like. Its early concepts intended it to be a turn-based rogue-like but the developers opted for a real-time action game instead.